# why useEffect is called infinitely

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In useEffect in my react component I get data and I update a state, but I don't know why the useEffect is always executed:

```
const Comp1 = () => {
    const [studies, setStudies]= useState([]);
    React.useEffect( async()=>{
          await axios.get('/api/expert/',
         )
        .then((response) => {
          setStudies(response.data.studies);     
    
        },  (error) => {
          console.log(error );
        })
          console.log("called+ "+ studies);
    
    },[studies]);
    return(
         <Comp2 studies={studies}/>
          )

}
```

Here is my second Component used in the first component...

```
 const Comp2 = (props) => {
        const [studies, setStudies]= useState([]);
        React.useEffect( ()=>{

              setStudies(props.studies)
        
        },[props.studies, studies]);


        return(
             studies.map((study)=>{console.log(study)})
    
    }
```

Comment: The callback in `useEffect` will be called after the first render and then again every time the dependencies change. You have `studies` in the dependencies array, meaning every time `studies` is updated, the callback is run again.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't update `studies`, I updated my code to better explain

Answer (score 2):

***EDIT***

```
const Comp2 = (props) => {

  // for some brief time props.studies will be an empty array, []
  // you need to decide what to do while props.studies is empty.

  // you can show some loading message, show some loading status,
  // show an empty list, do whatever you want to indicate
  // progress, dont anxious out your users
  return (
    props.studies.map((study)=>{console.log(study)}
  )
}
```

You useEffect hook depends on the updates that the state studies receive. Inside this useEffect hook you update studies. Can you see that the useEffect triggers itself?

A updates B. A runs whenever B is updated. (goes on forever)

How I'd do it?

```
const Comp1 = () => {
  const [studies, setStudies]= useState([]);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const asyncCall = async () => {
      await axios.get('/api/expert/',
      )
      .then((response) => {
        setStudies(response.data.studies);     
      }, (error) => {
        console.log(error );
      })
      
      console.log("called+ "+ studies);
    }
      
    asyncCall();
  }, []);

  return(
    <Comp2 studies={studies}/>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, The thing that making me crazy is studies is not changing value, althought the useEffect updates itself without stop, I will update my code

Comment: @OussamaEddahri `studies` *is* changing. Arrays and objects are compared by reference, so even if the entries in the array are the same, the array itself is actually new. This is why the `useEffect` continues to re-run.

Comment: You comp2 needs an useEffect? Check my edit.

Comment: Let me know how it goes now @OussamaEddahri

Answer (score 0):

`useEffect()` has dependency array which causes it to execute if any value within it updates. Here, `setStudies` updates `studies` which is provided as dependency array and causes it to run again and so on. To prevent this, remove `studies` from the dependency array.
Refer: [How the useEffect Hook Works (with Examples)](https://daveceddia.com/useeffect-hook-examples/#run-useeffect-on-state-change)